# For how big object heap should be used instead stack?

Tags: c++, stack-overflow

I am wondering how big object are too big for stack? If we are talking about normal PC (either Windows or some Linux). I've tried to find answer but all I found was allocate on heap if objects are too big. But what is too big? Few KB? or few hundreds of KB? I know that it is usually not an issue but it is bothering me since I don't know the answer.

Some code:

```
int main()
{
    int a[1000][300]; /* enough for stack overflow :) on Visual Studio 2012 without any specific setting. int a[1000][250] is Ok */
    return 0; 
}
```

Some more:

```
int main()
{
    MySmallClass a; // I want to use RAII
    MyBigClass b; // ouch I shouldn't do it
    unique_ptr<MyBigClass> c(new MyBigClass()) // So I would do something like this to keep RAII
    return 0; 
}
```

Since Visual Studio seems to have problem with stack allocation as big as only 1MB it seems to be reasonable to allocate on stack object with maximal size of few KB since stack can go quite deep. It is not much and with 3rd party object I even don't know (because I don't want to know at all) how big they are I can only expect that they will be reasonable small.

I actually encounter this kind of problem only once when I made big static array to test some performance. So in real life it is probably not common problem, but still...

Comment: Its not Visual Studio -- it's Windows that gives you a 1MB default stack size. If you control the thread creation, you can just ask for more.

Comment: `It is not much and with 3rd party object I even don't know (because I don't want to know at all) how big they are `  Any 3rd party library that gives you objects that can easily blow out the stack is IMO a low quality library.

Comment: Why is this so important? Just pick an arbitrary limit, and then go back to doing useful work. If you can't pick yourself, then the *perfect* limit is 65536 bytes, obviously.

Comment: You can specify the total stack capacity when compiling your program or within the program itself, depending on the compiler and OS. By default, it's somewhere between 1MB and 8MB. But, of course, the practical limit you set yourself per function (its local variables) should be at least a thousand times lower, IMHO. So, a few KB would be a good ball-park figure. Just avoid large static arrays, and by large, I would say roughly above 100 or so elements. There won't be much relative performance benefit in avoiding the heap when data is that much anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple answer to this question.

A single object? 
Some run time determined quantity?
Is the object created every loop or recursive call?

Because stack overflows can be difficult to recognize, all these choices can influence how careful you want to be when choosing to put a big object on the stack.

---

In the embedded systems I have worked on, stack vs heap was seldom discussed.  Instead, the issue was simply "what is the lifetime of the object".

And, perhaps surprisingly, most of the 'important' objects were created at start-up, and never destructed. i.e. they lasted until the system was reset or powered down.

In that embedded environment, the important objects were in the heap.

---

Of course, in a substantial system, there were also many objects that only lasted to the end of a function (or method).

These short term objects would either fit (or not) into the stack associated with the single thread using them.  There was no run-time stack size change mechanism (that I knew of) in that version of vxWorks.  Each task (which I think correspond to linux threads) had a stack size determined at compile time.  And we did, on occasion, overflow the stack.

When you discover and convince yourself you have stack overflow in your program, there are 2 solutions (or maybe more)

- In one particular case, my team's decision was to expand the specific threads stack size.  The overflow  was unique to that thread.
- In several others, we new'd the object to the heap at the beginning of the function, and deleted it at exit.  Simple, right?

Is that the only two choices?   Maybe.

So, if you have to have a number, I would say look for someone's else's rule-of-thumb.

---

As a practiced developer of embedded systems, I would describe my choices as:

- I keep non-trivial objects on the heap.
- small quantities of any comparatively simple objects on the stack.
- life-time issues can only push things from stack to the heap
- bigger size can only push things from stack to the heap

Personally, I am very comfortable using new and delete, and have opinions about ownership issues.  However ... my 'style' choices are not for every one.  And there is a lot of literature suggesting that, ultimately, complexity will confuse any knowledge of what task owns what objects (and thus which task should delete which objects)

Now, figure out what *you* mean by non-trival, and simple.

---

With respect to std::vector, and std::strings, std::stringstream, and map's, well these are all relatively complex objects (IMHO).

But if you use sizeof(), they are surprisingly small, even when filled.  I think this implies that these are each a 'front end' for heap access.

On the other hand, they perform well, and perhaps are doing something else, (not heap related)   But I have not looked into it.

More to learn.